# Как скопировать страницу в Wordpress без плагинов?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно скопировать страницу в Wordpress без плагинов, чтобы на ее основе создать другую. Как это сделать без использования плагинов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/duplicate-post.html